# Regular graph (Homework)

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph and $ad(G) = \frac{2|E|}{|V|}$ the average degree of $G$. 
$$
mad(G) = max ( ad(H) : H \le G ) \text{ the maximum average degree of a subgraph of $G$}
$$

We know that $\chi(G)\gt k$.

Proof that $G$ has a $k-regular$ subgraph.

I've been chewing this for quite a while. Any pointers that may lead me to a rigorous proof ?

EDIT : $mad(G) \le k$ and $k \ge 3$. I left it out by accident.

Comment: So we're supposed to prove that, if $G$ is a simple graph and $\mathrm{mad}(G)\le k\lt\chi(G)$, then $G$ has a $k$-regular subgraph? Is that it? Can you tell us what book the problem is from?

Comment: Yes. If $mad(G) \le k \lt \chi(G)$ Then $G$ has a k-regular subgraph. I do not know if it is from a book, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea. You have a number $k$ and a simple graph $G$ satisfying the condition $\mathrm{mad}(G)\le k\lt\chi(G)$. Among the (induced) subraphs of $G$, find a **minimal** subgraph $H$ which still satisfies that condition. In other words, $H$ is an induced subgraph of $G$, and $\mathrm{mad}(H)\le k\lt\chi(H)$, but deleting any vertex from $H$ will cause the condition to fail. Can you do anything with that?

**Hint:** If $H-v$ is $k$-colorable for every vertex $v\in V(H)$, and if $H$ is not $k$-colorable, then $\delta(H)\ge k$, where $\delta$ is the minimum degree.

Comment: What I meant was, remove as many vertices as you can without losing the condition $k\lt\chi(H)$. You now have $\chi(H)\gt k$ but you cannot remove any vertex without lowering the chromatic number to $k$. (This is called a "critically $k+1$-chromatic graph" or something like that--have you heard of those?) What does that tell you about the degrees of vertices in $H$?

Comment: In general, removing a vertex may lower the chromatic number **without** lowering the maximum degree. For example $C_5$ has maximum degree $2$ and chromatic number $3$; removing any vertex lowers the chromatic number but the maximum degree is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If the graph has a $k$-regular subgraph then the mad($G$) = $k$.  This means that if there are any graphs with $\chi(G) > mad(G) +1$ then the result cannot be true because you could pick $k=\mbox{mad}(G) +1$ and get a contradiction.